# Plotting stacked bar chart side by side having 2 value axis using Spotfire

Tags: bar-chart, spotfire, stacked-chart

How can I plot a stacked bar chart side by side having 2 value columns on Y axis and one period(year) column on x axis.
For some reason the visualisation splits out two separate bar charts.
[image: Stacked bar chart]
However I want the two columns Sum([RCN selection]) and sum([Adjusted Asset]) to be plotted next to each other on a common x axis ([Forcast Year]).
Please also note the bars are coloured based on the subset as shown below.

[image: Colour]

Side by side bar after Trellis has been cleared.
[image: Side by side]

I however need a side by side stacked bar. Unfortunately when I add the desired dimension to PROPERTIES-->COLORS , the chart dies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have your chart trellised. Turn this feature off

- Right Click On Chart > Properties > Trellis
- Be sure everything is set to (None) by removing any columns / rows / pages

Then, if you want them side by side

- Right Click on Chart > Click Side-by-Side Bars

You can adjust your coloring as you want in your post.

Comment: Thanks @scsimon. I am able to get the side by side bars. I however want to plot a side by side stacked bar. Please refer the new attachment

Comment: You can’t have both @Shaktirajjena

Comment: I thought so, thanks @Scsimon maybe I will work without it then